# Beginner in Java..Error while using system.out

Tags: java

I am a novice Java student and am trying to complete a program that uses the scanner to input  students' names,marks and then to calculate grade for each student. I am stuck as I keep getting below error while printing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
     QualifiedName
    - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
    - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
     MethodHeaderName
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
```

The error comes in the print statment

package day2.examples;
    import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class inputData {
    /*String stdName;
    int mathMarks;
    int engMark;`enter code here`
    int sciMark;*/


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String stdName = input.nextLine();
    int mathMark = input.nextInt();
    int engMark = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Insert Name Value");

    int grade () {
        if ((mathMark + engMark ) <50) {
            return(1);
        } else  return(2);




    }



}
```

Comment: You need to put code inside a method! It cannot be roaming around inside a class :)

Comment: Please first learn Java, then program in Java, not the other way around.

Comment: @m0skit0: he is learning. None of us are born knowing this stuff, and most all of us trip a bit early on (and later) as we learn the language.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sure, nobody is born with knowledge, that's why I said he should learn first before trying to code. I'm trying to help him avoid the mistakes I've made.

Comment: @m0skit0: hell, I learn most from the mistakes I've made, meaning, I've learned a **lot**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got code that belongs inside of a method or constructor hanging out naked in the class. Perhaps you want to create a main method and put your code in there.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputData {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*String stdName;
        int mathMarks;
        int engMark;`enter code here`
        int sciMark;*/

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String stdName = input.nextLine();
        int mathMark = input.nextInt();
        int engMark = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert Name Value");
    }

    public static int grade () {
        if ((mathMark + engMark ) < 50) {
            return 1;
        } else  {
            return 2;    
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your code inside some method, constructor or block.

You can do something like following

```
 class InputData {

     int engMark;
     int mathMark;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void getInput(){
    System.out.println("Insert Name Value");
    String stdName = input.nextLine();
    mathMark = input.nextInt();
    engMark = input.nextInt();
    }

    int grade() {
        if ((mathMark + engMark) < 50) {
            return (1);
        } else
            return (2);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
    InputData inputData = new InputData();
    inputData.getInput();
    System.out.println(inputData.grade());
    }

}
```

Also take care of java naming conventions. makes life easier. Like class name should be `InputData` and not `inputData`.

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot.. Here I am trying to create class and want to use this class through object. Whats is the problem in that.Pls explain me.

Comment: You cannot do it the way you are currently doing. There are rules be it any programming language. I would recommend go through some basic java tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all of your code into a `main method` if you want it to run. Declare a main method as follows:

```
class InputData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Put all of your code here
    }
}
```

Anything outside of the main method will not run, this is how just how Java works.

In addition, a word about Java naming conventions, class names (the thing after `class` at the top of the program) should always be capitalized, and variable names should always start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add import statements as well as add a public static void main(String args[]) method. The main method is start point of any java program. Try compiling it.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class InputData {

    private static String stdName;
    private static in mathMark;
    private static int engMark;


    public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        stdName = input.nextLine();
        mathMark = input.nextInt();
        engMark = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Insert Name Value");
    }

    private static int grade () {
            if ((mathMark + engMark ) <50) {
                return 1;
            } else  return 2;
    }
    }
```